# Task Killer not resetting stack

Tags: android

My application has a main Activity A and that does a StartActivity on Activity B.  If somebody uses a Task Killer (e.g., Advanced Task Killer), the application is killed but when they run the app again I see the Application object is being built (onCreate called) and then it goes right into Activity B not Activity A.  The Manifest has A being the Launcher Activity.

I also see the scenario if I run A, then Activity B, bring down notification list and run Task Killer to kill my app, and press the Back key, it creates the Application object and then Activity B object.

Any ideas on how to prevent this behavior?  Activity B assumes that Activity A has already run.  I am able to kludge this but have a boolean in the Application object which is set on Activity A.  In Activity B onCreate, if that global flag is not set, I do a finish().  Must be a better way to handle this since I have quite a few activities that would experience the same behavior.

Comment: I too have run into this problem.  Task Killer is a nasty app that pulls the rug out from under the apps it "kills".  Unfortunately, it does not clean up everything.  I have multiple activities that depend upon an application state that is set by another activity. @sjay did you figure anything out here?

Comment: You really cannot rely on specific activities happening in a certain order because of this.  What I did is persist what I could when focus leaving window.

Answer (score 2):

Activity B should almost never assume any other Activity has run. Activities are meant to be stand alone units. If B *must* depend on A then there should be some test for a precondition and if it fails, opens ActivityA via an Intent.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of keeping the flag in Application you may persist it in `SharedPreferences` - then your Activity B will always know the correct value of the flag.